# Visual Studio 2015, using GIT extension, and Database project .dbmdl file

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, database-project

GIT in Visual Studio is reporting the .dbmdl file is in use by another process.

When it does this, all the VS change tracking stops - no files show as changed.

Remove my DB project from the solution, and immediately, all the changed files show as changed.

The .dbmdl file is some kind of local cache, and is not meant to be checked into source control. And I have made sure it is not.

How can I fix this, and have my DB project in the solution?

Comment: A new version of this same problem exists for a .jfm with similar problems to the .dbmdl.  Again, .gitignore it and it fixes VS git problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed this issue by specifically naming the .dbmdl file in my .gitignore file.

From that point on GIT in VS completely ignored it, and changes always show up.

Comment: There's a Git repo on GitHub that contains several standard .gitignore files you can use. There are some for VS projects that work pretty well, but need a little tweaking to include various XML files like those used for publish profiles. You may want to check those out for templates to use if you haven't already.

Comment: Yeah I know, thanks man! it's here: github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Spent literally 5 hours with this... finally figured out this is related with this .jfm file, so I planned to gitignore..., but I just wanted to know what is jfm file... google search .jfm I found this answer within a second :-).